# Autofill batch Processing output path for Split Vector Layer tool

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, batch

The Split Vector Layer Batch Process Interface does not allow for setting output files like other processing algorithms do (i.e. Dissolve et al.)
Instead, you must set an Output Directory which does not seem to Autofill for the output files.

Anyone have suggestions for setting Output Directory/or output files in Batch Process Split Vector Layers?

Comment: You only define the Folder location. The output shapefile names are constructed like this: input_fc + '_' + columnValue, in the output folder.

Comment: Understood about setting the Output Folder Location. My issue is in batch process I cannot double click the header to Auto-fill all the extra rows. This works for me in other batch processing tools.

Comment: ok, maybe the best option is copy/paste from one cell to another.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. My batch process is for ~1000 files.

Comment: I am surprised there isn't an auto-fill for the rows like there is for output files in other processing tools.

Comment: @NotHotdog It's probably just an oversight. Consider opening a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

Found it -- there is an available plug-in called "Split vector layer by attribute" that is different from the default "Split vector layer" in QGIS. This plug in allows for the auto-fill functionality for output file names.